# Need to add spaces between labels in javascript

Tags: javascript, label, spaces

i want to make some spaces between those labels:

```
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Monday') + "</label> " +
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Tusday') + "</label> " +
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Wensday') + "</label> " +
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Thirsday') + "</label> " +
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Friday') + "</label> " +
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Saturday') + "</label> " +
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Sunday') + "</label> " +
```

Comment: Style them with CSS? `label{display:inline-block;padding:1em}`

Comment: css margin or padding

Comment: `"<label> " + currentItem.get_item('Monday') + " </label>"` or  `"<label>&nbsp;" + currentItem.get_item('Monday') + "&nbsp;</label>" ` or `"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Monday') + "</label>&nbsp;"`

Comment: want to embed css with javascript code

Comment: use character entities to fulfill your task **&nbsp;**

Comment: thanks guys
your answers are very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style them by adding margin or padding to your labels.

```
label{
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Or if you need a white space so then use

```
&nbsp;
```

instead of ' ' like this:

```
"<label>" + currentItem.get_item('Monday') + "</label>&nbsp;" +
```